# ANTLR 4.7 CharStreams.fromFileName(s) is not being found

Tags: java, antlr4

This is a minimized test case. It should compile. The commented out string is the 4.6 version and it does compile and work. So my build environment would seem to be correct.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class xx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream input = new
            //     org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRFileStream("file name here");  // compiles
            org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream input = new
                org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams.fromFileName("file name here");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

$ javac xx.java
xx.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
            org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream         input = new org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams.fromFileName("file name here");
                                                                                                ^
  symbol:   class fromFileName
  location: class CharStreams
1 error
```

I'm upgrading from ANTLR 4.6 to 4.7. One of the changes is deprecation of ANTLRInputStream and ANTLRFileStream. So what was (taken straight from *The Excellent and Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference*) :

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;                  // http://www.antlr.org/
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

String f ...

ANTLRInputStream    input = new ANTLRFileStream(f);
```

is now something like:

```
CharStream          input = new CharStreams.fromFileName(f);
```

I've installed 4.7 in /usr/local/lib/ and I compile my grammar with no changes or errors. But when I compile the resulting java I get:

```
java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7-complete.jar xx.g4
javac -Xlint:deprecation *.java
xxasm.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
                CharStream          input = new CharStreams.fromFileName(f);
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class fromFileName
  location: class CharStreams
1 error
```

My classpath and java version are:

```
CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7-complete.jar:/usr/local/lib/jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar:/usr/local/lib/junit-4.12-sources.jar:/usr/local/lib/gson-2.8.1.jar

javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131

OSX 10.12.5
```

Any ideas? Everything looks fine when looking at antlr-4.7-complete.jar with javap:

```
...
public static org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream fromFileName(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException;
```

Turning on the -verbose flag:

```
...
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7-complete.jar(org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStreams.class)]]
dwasm.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
                CharStream          input = new CharStreams.fromFileName(f);
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class fromFileName
  location: class CharStreams
```

Also, doesn't work:

```
CharStream          input = new org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams.fromFileName(f);

org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream input = new
    org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams.fromFileName("file name goes here");
```

od -c

```
0004720    t   i   m   e   .   C   h   a   r   S   t   r   e   a   m   s
0004740    .   f   r   o   m   F   i   l   e   N   a   m   e   (   "   f
0004760    i   l   e       n   a   m   e       h   e   r   e   "   )   ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new CharStreams.fromFileName(f);
```

should just be

```
CharStreams.fromFileName(f);
```

For whatever reason, the error message is terrible when you make that mistake.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something dead simple that I just wasn't seeing. Again, thanks.

Comment: @jacobm all functions of the CharStreams class are static, so it is not correct to use "new".